# Rendering ASP.NET MVC ViewResult HTML as image without third party components

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, html-to-pdf, html-to-jpeg

is there a way to render ViewResult or PartialViewResult as an image?

I have tried to get ViewResult as string and I got a string containing html as it should be, but I need to render that html to image. If it is possible - with styles and images.

I have an idea to get some browser output for this html on server and capture result to an image, but how it can be done in practice I don't know at this time.
If you have any ideas, please, help.

Please do not suggest any third party components. Just tell if it is impossible to do by standart .NET classes.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [How to render an image using the WebBrowser control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-render-or-convert-7064e4e2)

```
public class HtmlToBitmapConverter 
{ 
    private const int SleepTimeMiliseconds = 5000; 

    public Bitmap Render(string html, Size size) 
    { 
        var browser = CreateBrowser(size); 

        browser.Navigate("about:blank"); 
        browser.Document.Write(html); 

        return GetBitmapFromControl(browser, size); 
    } 

    public Bitmap Render(Uri uri, Size size) 
    { 
        var browser = CreateBrowser(size); 

        NavigateAndWaitForLoad(browser, uri, 0); 

        return GetBitmapFromControl(browser, size); 
    } 

    public void NavigateAndWaitForLoad(WebBrowser browser, Uri uri, int waitTime) 
    { 
        browser.Navigate(uri); 
        var count = 0; 

        while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) 
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(SleepTimeMiliseconds); 

            Application.DoEvents(); 
            count++; 

            if (count > waitTime / SleepTimeMiliseconds) 
            { 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    private WebBrowser CreateBrowser(Size size) 
    { 
        return 
            new WebBrowser 
            { 
                ScrollBarsEnabled = false, 
                ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true, 
                Size = size 
            }; 
    } 

    private Bitmap GetBitmapFromControl(WebBrowser browser, Size size) 
    { 
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height); 

        NativeMethods.GetImage(browser.Document.DomDocument, bitmap, Color.White); 
        return bitmap; 
    } 
}
```

Then it's as easy as

```
var image = new HtmlToBitmapConverter()
                .Render(new Uri(urlTextBox.Text), pictureBox.Size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my previous suggestion. It was not correct, really. Now I understand what you want. But if you don't like the idea to use the third-party solutions the only way is to write your own parser and it's not easy task. Or you could try to use WebBrowser class and its method DrawToBitmap how it's described here http://englestone.blogspot.com/2009/06/generate-screenshot-previews-with-c.html

Comment: That's not correct, he's not asking to download an image.  He wants to render the web page as an image, then download it.  The downloading is easy, the rendering less so.

Comment: Oh, really? I still don't understand. You mean the task is return of the image for example if view has tables the image should include tables?